# Edge extraction of an image in imagemagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, edge-detection

I am working on image processing in imagemagick and I've got [this](http://barafranca.nl/im-no-cheater)! image to process. I am very new to image processing and specially to imagemagick so I don't know much about it however I've tried to solve this problem by applying different techniques like blurring,sharpening, labeling, background changing with different mask values but no use. Please anyone tell me that what transformations or techniques should I apply to extract edges of characters in the above image. Please tell here or give link to any resources where I could read more about it. I've tried to read the examples at IM's website but that all went upon my head.Any help in this regard will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: beyond the scope of stack overflow

Comment: because you have not shown us what have you tried?

Comment: Edited the question. Is it acceptable now???

Comment: Now you can only hope.Because dude it is really hard

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how to download the image you have linked. But there are lots of ways to create edge images in ImageMagick.

```
convert image -edge 1 result
```

Also see
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#difference
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/convolve/#edgedet